# Valence user search returns 404

Tags: desire2learn, valence

The call executed is  **…/users/**
   with parameter **orgDefinedId = “e5555555”**.

As per documentation, an array of UserData should be returned.

In  practice, when such user doesn’t exist, the call returns 404 "Resource Not Found" (not documented).

Comment: It was pointed to myself that this one was not answered because there is no explicit question asked (though it was completely obvious what the question is). So, I'll ask a question.

I see 3 possibilities:
1. I've used this call wrongly.
2. Documentation is wrong.
3. There is a bug in Valence.

Which one happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documentation oversight. The answer is:

- If you used the action with no query parameter filters, the action returns a paged result set containing the users it can find. If, because of the calling user's role permissions, the action can find no users, it returns with a 200 status code, but an empty result set.
- If you used the action with a query parameter filter (`userName` or `orgDefinedId`), the action returns the matching user record(s) it can find; if it can find no matching user(s), the action returns with a 404 status code.

The documentation has been updated to clarify this.